# How to jump specific page using pnp js for sharepoint pagination

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, spfx-webparts, paging, pnpjs

I am using pnp js Get Paged Items for pagination in my SPFx webpart.

```
sp.web.lists.getByTitle("MyCustomList").items.top(10).getPaged();
```

Suppose I have 150 data in a list. I set 10 data for a page. So my page size will be 15. Suppose now I am in page 2 and I want to jump page no 8. Is there
any way in sharepoint pnp js pagination to jump to a specific page directly?